# Dependecies for CardView and RecyclerView in SDK version 28

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to add CardView and RecyclerView dependencies in my Android Studio Project for SDK version 28. Upon building the project, I get the message, "Gradle Project Sync Failed. Basic Functionality will not work properly".

build.gradle(Module:app) file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.kavyabarnadhyahazarika.quarterallotmentiocl"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
       }
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
buildToolsVersion '28.0.0'
          }

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Error Messages: 
Failed to resolve: com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0
Failed to resolve: com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0

I have tried both build and clean project.

Also if these dependencies are not supported on SDK version 28, how do I resolve the issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no `28.0.0` final release as of yet - just like your `appcompat-v7` dependency, `cardview-v7` and `recyclerview-v7` should have a version of `28.0.0-alpha3`:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
```

Comment: Did you mean to paste in some additional error message?

Comment: Failed to resolve: com.android.support.cardview-v7:28.0.0-alpha3:
Also, Project Build Failed.

Comment: You have a period instead of a semi-colon. `com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0-alpha3`

Comment: Thanks, that resolved the issue. But, now getting a new one: AAPT2 error: check logs for details.

Comment: If your dependency question is solved, you should mark this question as solved, search to see if anyone has already asked a question about your new issue, and then ask a new question with your full reproduction steps and error message if you cannot find an answer.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me.

```
// RecyclerView
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'

// CardView
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:+'
```

Answer (score 3):

**Here's a working solution.**

**replace the following dependencies**

```
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
```

**or**

```
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
```

**with the below implementations**

```
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
```

I hope it helps.